# Collect all strings between pattern1 and pattern2 but only print the string in between which matches pattern3

Tags: python, regex, sed

I am trying to dealing with a large test log file which prints a log of tests logs. Test blocks starts with `"start running"` (`pattern1` below) and end with `"test end"` (`pattern2` below); between those two strings there is an `"Error Message"` (`pattern3`) that displays detailed error info.

Here is what I want to do and what I have done:

1. search for log file (`test.log`) and print out "full" test logs using sed:

   ```
    sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/p' test.log
   ```

   this will collect complete logs of all tests
2. I want to move one step further based on step 1, to only print out lines containing "Error Message" (`pattern3`) and also lines containing pattern1  pattern2. How can I complete it in a one-line sed command?

3.Can I use Python `re` module to solve this problem as well?

Comment: Please provide some realistic input strings to play with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer of question 2 : how to print out strings containing pattern3 :
"sed -n '/pattern1/,/pattern2/{/pattern3/p}' test.log "

But this command cannot print out pattern1 and pattern2 , still trying to figure out.

(hmm, not sure why previous answer/comments was all deleted , this is my first StackOverflow question posted welcome any suggestion :) )